# Refresh page with framesets on button click

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, refresh, reload, frameset

I have a web application built around a frameset. The main page (with the frameset layout) is index.aspx. After the user logs in, if there are any alerts it redirects the main content frame to an alerts page with a confirmation button on it. When they click this button I want the index.aspx to be reloaded. If I use the response.redirect("index.aspx") on button click it reloads the main content frame with another frameset.

The server-side button click sets a flag within the database so that the user doesnt see the alert again.

My question is how do I force a complete reload of the entire frameset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of them if you can, but until then you will have to do it with `JavaScript`:

**sorry about the c# example, don't care for vb.net*

[How to do a Response.Redirect to another frame](http://weblogs.asp.net/ksamaschke/archive/2003/02/23/2831.aspx)

```
//add this startup script to your button event handler
String csname1 = "FrameRedirect";  
Type cstype = this.GetType();

// Get a ClientScriptManager reference from the Page class.
ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;

// Check to see if the startup script is already registered.
if (!cs.IsStartupScriptRegistered(cstype, csname1))
{
  string url = "index.aspx";
  String cstext1 = "parent.framename.location.href='" + url + "';"
  //or
  //String cstext1 = "parent.framename.location.replace('" + url + "');"
  cs.RegisterStartupScript(cstype, csname1, cstext1, true);
}
```

Comment: thanks I found (Response.Write("<script>parent.location.href='../admin/login.aspx';</script>");) right after you answered. Thank you again